# MoreUnit Plugin for Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-13, intellij-plugin, moreunit

I am looking for a [moreUnit](http://moreunit.sourceforge.net/) like plugin for Intellij

This are the features I mostly use and miss in Intellij:

1. create a new test method from the method under test
2. Marker on method under test indicating that a corresponding test method exist
3. jump to the test method (not only the class) from method under test.
4. execute corresponding test method from method under test.

I saw there is plugin called MoreUnit but the only thing it does is jump to test/to class under test. This is function does intellij out of the box with CMD+SHIFT+T.

Comment: You can execute any individual method annotated with @Test without any plugins. On windows press ctrl-shift-F10 when your cursor is placed in a test method and the editor window has focus.

Comment: When you press (windows) ctrl-shift-t while your cursor is in a class and the editor window is focused, and no test exists for that class, intellij prompts you to create a test class, and test methods for individual public methods on the class under test.

Comment: It's better to use code-coverage than a 'test method exists' marker. Most teams don't write a test method for every public method exposed by a given class. For example, most people will not test specifically for simple getters and setters. IntelliJ will show test coverage live in the editor.

Comment: You trying to compare apple and oranges. CC can maybe be seen as addition to/replacement for point 2. But what about 1,3 and 4?

Comment: What do you mean by "corresponding test method" - since a method Xxx may have multiple tests, testXxxPositive, testXxxNegative, etc...

Comment: @vikingsteve in that case moreuint provides a list of test method you can jump to. when running a test out of method under test, it will use all corresponding test methods and execute them. (you should try out this tools, it really makes life easier)

Comment: Are you good at writing intellij plugins @Vadimo? Sounds like a fine idea, if you're up to writing it :) ...

Comment: And actually the default "Go To Test..." function could be better also...

Comment: Yep, being able to run the tests of the current file would be great. In maven projects, at least, it's quite simple (by convention) and moreunit works fine on eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few years there is now a port of moreunit to intellij

https://github.com/MoreUnit/org.moreunit.intellij.plugin

Comment: I don't understand how to use it. The plugin I find in intellij is the one you linked here. But like you stated in your opening post, there ist not much more than jumping from/to test class, is there? Can't really figure it out :( I also search the 4 points you stated. Could you explain how you today achieve these, point by point?